# How to fix Typescript errors on recursive reduce function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Typescript and I wrote a very rudimentary implementation of JSON stringify. The code works as expected, but my types are a bit messed up on the part where I recursively stringify nested arrays. Any help is appreciated :D

Here is a link to the TS playground and there it shows all the errors I get.
[PLAYGROUND LINK](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=34&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMBSBlA8gOSgXlkVU1ywCMArCAY2CgB8oBnYAJyQDsBzRqTgK4BbchDZ9yAe0kIIcTnzTNJnAIJs2cEAFgAUHq7AxAMzg1oSles0goEAB5HOKZlGtaAPKw48+gkWIS0rLyfAAicEZ88Mjo2DgU1HSKymoaWgB8UADeUAC+egacRmym5kSxpAlUtPTZegCQANr2AFws7FzcALrt3l1+wqLiTFIycgpMEVFMlmk2egX6ug5gkmz0NCqsHT7cSMa2hAAUXGACwO0xJPEAlFCt-b74WfW6UB8HUKec5-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-gBQEgaaeQQaGZ5vq2wkMtkhmLAA3EAA)

```js
type ValidJSON = ValidJSONObject | string | number | boolean | JsonArray

interface JsonArray extends Array<string | number | boolean | Date | ValidJSONObject | JsonArray> { }

interface ValidJSONObject {
    [x: string]: string | number | boolean | Date | JsonArray
}

export const stringify = (input: ValidJSON) :string => {
   if (input === null)
    return 'null'
  else if (input.constructor === String)
    return '"' + input.replace(/"|\n/g, (x:string) =>  x === '"' ? '\\"' :'\\n') + '"'
  else if (input.constructor === Number)
    return String(input)
  else if (input.constructor === Boolean)
    return input ? 'true' : 'false'
  else if (input.constructor === Array)
    return '[' + input.reduce((acc, v) => {
      if (v === undefined)
        return [...acc, 'null']
      else
        return [...acc, stringify(v)]
    }, []).join(',') + ']'
  else if (input.constructor === Object)
    return '{' + Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, k) => {
      if (input[k] === undefined)
        return acc
      else
        return [...acc, stringify(k) + ':' + stringify(input[k])]
    }, []).join(',') + '}'
  else
    return '{}'
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduce method need type argument if the accumulator type cannot be inferenced.

For example. The accumulator of following code doesn't tell what type of the array is.

```
[1,2,3].reduce((acc, cur) => ([...acc, cur+'']), [])
```

So you need to pass type argument like follows.

```
[1,2,3].reduce<string[]>((acc, cur) => ([...acc, cur+'']), [])
```

I also fixed the all of errors.
The changes as follows.

1. Added Date type to the ValidJSON type definition.
2. Added `string[]` to type argument of reduce method.
3. Cast the input as `(input as ValidJSONObject)`

The generated javascript code is the same of yours.
I hope this will help!

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#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-6XKA6xHOiBsjqI6zWtG0q0RnH2x1E53x9U+LIgdN+zOMxHNNmc2swlAkiABKncZo9bInE42GhygBuyve6N9ONnTYEnggli4EBQbd9-sZzTxx+ncuRoIQiJ6S6hVYgN-3HYUR5PNBne26hxAJ3n19pX0KOUx3uPFKEkLgTkRGVTQ5JkegrL470jO0cxjJ02BdN1gVqOg2wPJE8h7KAcIdABrCAQGYaMQP7Qdh32McJynN85VIjpyJASRbRuaoyCoOoF3yB9kMne0oDgbweMSPjUmAe5mlIno1w3LdOB3Pc6SfcS32Eu9hIzBln2PPFTw-HgvxOUizSZNoiMVCzo3EyTiGk5J+NwhSenuP9fUAqBgNA8DOEg6DrMRQoEPDe9-3bQymTyCKlgAbiAA)

```js
type ValidJSON = ValidJSONObject | string | number | boolean | Date | JsonArray

interface JsonArray extends Array<string | number | boolean | Date | ValidJSONObject | JsonArray> { }

interface ValidJSONObject {
    [x: string]: string | number | boolean | Date | JsonArray
}

export const stringify = (input: ValidJSON) :string => {
   if (input === null)
    return 'null'
  else if (input.constructor === String)
    return '"' + input.replace(/"|\n/g, (x:string) =>  x === '"' ? '\\"' :'\\n') + '"'
  else if (input.constructor === Number)
    return String(input)
  else if (input.constructor === Boolean)
    return input ? 'true' : 'false'
  else if (input.constructor === Array)
    return '[' + input.reduce<string[]>((acc, v) => {
      if (v === undefined)
        return [...acc, 'null']
      else
        return [...acc, stringify(v)]
    }, []).join(',') + ']'
  else if (input.constructor === Object)
    return '{' + Object.keys(input).reduce<string[]>((acc, k: keyof ValidJSONObject) => {
      if ((input as ValidJSONObject)[k] === undefined)
        return acc
      else
        return [...acc, stringify(k) + ':' + stringify((input as ValidJSONObject)[k])]
    }, []).join(',') + '}'
  else
    return '{}'
};
```

Comment: Why is it not just `interface JsonArray extends Array<ValidJSON>`?

Comment: And also, why can properties of object not be other objects?

Comment: looks like I was on the right path with type assertions but I was not sure how to use them yet. Thank you so much for this!